# PHP miniwebsever file download

Tags: php, sockets

$httpsock = @socket_create_listen("9090");
  if (!$httpsock) {
    print "Socket creation failed!\n";
    exit;
  }
  while (1) {
    $client = socket_accept($httpsock);
    $input = trim(socket_read ($client, 4096));
    $input = explode(" ", $input);
    $input = $input[1];
    $fileinfo = pathinfo($input);

```
switch ($fileinfo['extension']) {
  default:
    $mime = "text/html";
}
if ($input == "/") {
  $input = "index.html";
}
$input = ".$input";
if (file_exists($input) && is_readable($input)) {
  echo "Serving $input\n";
  $contents = file_get_contents($input);
  $output = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: APatchyServer\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: $mime\r\n\r\n$contents";
} else {
  //$contents = "The file you requested doesn't exist.  Sorry!";
  //$output = "HTTP/1.0 404 OBJECT NOT FOUND\r\nServer: BabyHTTP\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n$contents";
  function openfile()
  {
  $filename = "a.pl";
  $file     = fopen($filename, 'r');
  $filesize = filesize($filename);
  $buffer   = fread($file, $filesize);
  $array    = array("Output"=>$buffer,"filesize"=>$filesize,"filename"=>$filename);
  return $array; 
  }

  $send   = openfile();
  $file   = $send['filename'];
  $filesize  = $send['filesize'];
  $output  = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n';
  $output .= "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
  $output .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"\r\n';
  $output .= "Content-Length:$filesize\r\n";
  $output .= "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
  $output .= "Cache-Control: private\n\n";
  $output .= $send['Output'];
  $output .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
  $output .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";

}
socket_write($client, $output);
socket_close ($client);
```

}
  socket_close ($httpsock);

Hello, I am snikolov i am creating a miniwebserver with php and i would like to know how i can send the client a file to download with his browser such as firefox or internet explore i am sending a file to the user to download via sockets, but the cleint is not getting the filename and the information to download can you please help me here,if i declare the file again i get this error in my server 

**Fatal error**:  Cannot redeclare openfile() (previously declared in C:\User
s\fsfdsf\sfdsfsdf\httpd.php:31) in **C:\Users\hfghfgh\hfghg\httpd.php** on li
ne **29**
, if its possible, i would like to know if the webserver can show much banwdidth the user request via sockets, perl has the same option as php but its more hardcore than php i dont understand much about perl, i even saw that a miniwebserver can show much the client user pulls from the server would it be possible that you can assist me with this coding, i much aprreciate it thank you guys.

Comment: You managed to put whole post in one sentence;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not sending the filename to the client, so how should it know which filename to use?

There is a drawback, you can provide the desired filename in the http header, but some browsers ignore that and always suggest the filename based on the last element in URL.
For example http://localhost/download.php?help.me would result in the sugested filename help.me in the file download dialogue.

see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_headers

Comment: i have got the filedownloading without any errors!, i would like to know how it would be possible to view the bandwidth when the cleint downloads the file howmuch stream is sent to the client i really thankful!

Comment: Where would you like to see that? I don't understand the question. You don't need to send the whole block at once. Just split it up in chunks and send them one by one and close the connection when you have transfered everything. Then you can report after each chunk what has been uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you run your `while (1)` loop you declare `openfile` function. You can declare function only once. Try to move `openfile` declaration outside loop.

Comment: i am getting this problem please help!, when i download the file the Length of the file is unspecified, i use wget and it states so including internet download manager

Comment: $output  = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n';
      $output .= "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
      $output .= "Content-Length: $filesize\r\n";
      $output .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"\r\n';
      $output .= "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
      $output .= "Cache-Control: private\n\n";
      $output .= $send['Output'];
      $output .= "Pragma: private\n\n";

Answer (score -3):

```
  $httpsock = @socket_create_listen("9090");
  if (!$httpsock) {
    print "Socket creation failed!\n";
    exit;
  }
  while (1) {
    $client = socket_accept($httpsock);
    $input = trim(socket_read ($client, 4096));


    $input = explode(" ", $input);

    $input = $input[1];

    $fileinfo = pathinfo($input);

    switch ($fileinfo['extension']) {
      default:
        $mime = "text/html";
    }
    if ($input == "/") {
      $input = "index.html";
    }
    $input = ".$input";
    if (file_exists($input) && is_readable($input)) {
      echo "Serving $input\n";
      $contents = file_get_contents($input);
      $output = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nServer: APatchyServer\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: $mime\r\n\r\n$contents";
    } else {
      //$contents = "The file you requested doesn't exist.  Sorry!";
      //$output = "HTTP/1.0 404 OBJECT NOT FOUND\r\nServer: BabyHTTP\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n$contents";

      $filename = "dada";
      $file     = fopen($filename, 'r');
      $filesize = filesize($filename);
      $buffer   = fread($file, $filesize);
      $send     = array("Output"=>$buffer,"filesize"=>$filesize,"filename"=>$filename);

      $file   = $send['filename'];

      $output  = 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n';
      $output .= "Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n";
      $output .= "Content-Length: $filesize\r\n";
      $output .= 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"\r\n';
      $output .= "Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n";
      $output .= "Cache-Control: private\n\n";
      $output .= $send['Output'];
      $output .= "Pragma: private\n\n";
     // $output .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
      //$output .= "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n";

    }
    socket_write($client, $output);
    socket_close ($client);
  }
  socket_close ($httpsock);
```